# WPF&MVVM: Добавление чекбоска в автоматически генерируемую таблицу

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Данная таблица, построенная с помощью `ListView` и `GridView` отображает данные (ID и полное имя), получаемые из `ModelView`:

```
<ListView Name="DataTable" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=people}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PersonID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FullName" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Как известно, `ListView` уже имеет встроенную функцию выделения, причём сразу нескольких пунктов. Не менее, не все начинающие пользователи до этого додумаются, потому я решил добавить по чекбоксу в каждую строку. Как это сделать, если вся таблица, кроме шапки, генерируется автоматически? Естественно, тот чекбокс, который я уже добавил, будет только в шапке.

Кстати, я ещё подумываю добавить по кнопке "редактировать" и "удалить" в каждую строку; вероятно это предстоит тем же способом делать. В итоге должно получиться что-то такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<ListView Name="DataTable" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=people}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="50px">
                <!-- Это колонка для чекбоксов но они не должны быть в шапке  -->
            </GridViewColumn>  
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PersonID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FullName" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="50px">
                <!-- Это колонка для кнопок "Редактировать" но они не должны быть в шапке  -->
            </GridViewColumn>  
            <GridViewColumn Width="50px">
                <!-- Это колонка для кнопок "Удалить" но они не должны быть в шапке  -->
            </GridViewColumn>  
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: "Кстати, я ещё подумываю добавить по кнопке "редактировать" и "удалить" в каждую строку; вероятно это предстоит тем же способом делать." просто добавьте их в разметку

Comment: @Foggy Finder, куда имеенно? Внутрь какого тэга?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, `CellTemplate` же: [Разметка](https://pastebin.com/cx4GULh8), [Скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9CFo.png)

Comment: А если надумаете изобразить что-то в шапке - используйте расширенную разметку для установки свойства Header (оно имеет тип object и может содержать любые контролы)

Comment: Только узнал про `Cell Template`! В уроках для новичков такого, конечно же, не было:) Спасибо за пример разметки!

Comment: Я не понял до конца чуть вопроса, она в этом была? Если так - оформлю ответ.

Comment: Да, в этом. Я не знал, как с ячейками работать при автоматической генерации данных.

Comment: Я просто думал, что у вас и столбцы автоматически генерируются, хотя, вроде, ListView так не может, это ведь только DataGrid делает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для изменения содержимого ячейки `GridView` переопределите `CellTemplate`.

Пример разметки, в котором показано как выровнять содержимое ячейки по правому краю (обратите внимание, что для этого переопределен стиль `ListViewItem`), а также как добавить в ячейку любой элемент (кнопки):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Имя" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Возраст">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Адрес" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"/>

            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <UniformGrid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,0"/>
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                </Style>
                            </UniformGrid.Resources>

                            <Button>
                                <Image Source="edit32.png"/>
                            </Button>

                            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorType=Window}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <Image Source="delete32.png"/>
                            </Button>
                        </UniformGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Получается такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того, чтобы поместить любые элементы в заголовок используйте расширенную разметку для свойства `Header`:

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
    <GridViewColumn.Header>
        <CheckBox Content="Имя"/>
    </GridViewColumn.Header>
</GridViewColumn>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: благодарю Вас за пример, Ваши ответы как всегда замечательные!