# WPF&MVVM: Работа с отдельными пунктами ListView при дочернем GridView

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Следующий вопрос, который у меня возник, когда я узнал о `CellTemplate` в теме [WPF&MVVM: Добавление чекбоска в автоматически генерируемую таблицу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729245/wpfmvvm-%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83): как же теперь работать с отдельными пунктами списка? Мы определили таблицу поколоночно, а чтобы работать с пунктами списка, то есть со строками (узнавать, какой из них выделен, узнавать, над каким из них висит курсор мыши и т. д.), нам, вероятно, нужно `<ListView.ItemTemplate>`. Тогда мы можем воспользоваться, например, свойством `SelectItem`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Staff}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
```

В качестве заготовки я взял на этот раз упрощённый пример из ответа на предыдущий вопрос (спасибо пользователю @Andrey):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Staff}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Имя" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Возраст" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Адрес" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"/>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Content="Редактировать">                            
                            <Button Content="Удалить">
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: А что конкретно-то нужно? Выделенный элемент - правильно `SelectedItem`, а что еще? Вы хотите какие-то стили переопределить или что?

Comment: @Андрей, во-первых, мне нужно получить доступ к экземпляру, который на данный момент выбран (чтобы VM знала, что мы на данный момент выбрали). Далее, его можно будет либо редактировать, либо удалить. Для этого нужно, чтобы программа по крайней мере знала, что именно мы будем удалять или редактировать. Потом, нужна связь между элементами одной строки - если её не будет, то мы можем выбрать одну строку, а удалить её кнопкой из другой строки. Аналогично с редактированием.

Comment: Посмотрите еще раз мой пример, там у меня на одной из кнопок висит команда + ей передается параметр, так вот этот параметр - именно тот User, на котором мы нажали кнопку.

Comment: ListView (как и любой ItemsControl) пробегает привязанную коллекцию и генерирует дочерние элементы, при этом он устанавливает текущий элемент коллекции в качестве DataContext текущему дочернему элементу. Поэтому мы можем передать в команду параметр `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` - это будет нужный элемент.

Comment: Почти понял! Скажите, а `c:PwBinding` - это что? И ещё спрошу: а для случая, когда выбрано несколько пунктов списка, выше сказанное тоже справедливо?

Comment: `c:PwBinding` - это собственное расширение разметки, случайно прописалось. Несколько пунктов - это как? Каждая строка имеет свой DataContext, несколько строчек можно удалить, если у вас кнопка отдельная для удаления, а не в строчке. [Пример удаления нескольких строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670865/218063)

Comment: С этим вопросом разобрались?

Comment: Почти. На данный момент не совсем понятны два момента: 1) `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` - это экземпляр сущностного класса, так? 2) Что по сути есть `DataContext`?

Comment: У вас есть коллекция Users, вы хотите удалить определенного User из нее. Вам нужно в команде написать что-то вроде: `Users.Remove(user)` Но откуда вам взять этого user? К каждой строке ListView у нас привязан определенный User, вот мы его и можем передать в качестве параметра в команду: `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`