# WPF&MVVM: Привязка свойств VM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

В вопросе [Получение данных во ViewModel из делегированного объекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729340/wpfmvvm-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE-viewmodel-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0) по поводу приведённого ниже кода View с привязками и паттерна MVVM в целом я понял следующее:

> В отображении имеющихся данных у нас свойства экземпляров, которые
>   передаются из VM и имена свойств экземпляров не могут не совпадать со
>   именами свойств модели. Что касается полей для ввода новых данных, то
>   там уже свойства VM. Получив значения этих свойств, мы используем их в
>   команде добавления нового экземпляра.

```
<!-- Отображение имеющихся данных -->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=staff}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <!-- ... -->
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PersonStringifiedId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PersonFullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <!-- ... -->


<!-- Ввод новых  данных -->
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="personStringifiedId"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="personFullName"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<Button Command="{Binding addNewPersonCommand}"/>
```

К сожалению, одного только понимания выше сказанного не хватило, чтобы благополучно связать новое свойство `VM` с элементом `View`. По образцу в ответе на вопрос [Добавление чекбоска в автоматически генерируемую таблицу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729245/wpfmvvm-%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83) я попытался привязать атрибуту `IsChecked` чекбокса свойство `IsSelected` ViewModel. Не вижу причины вводить это свойство в модель, потому на данный момент оно есть только во `ViewModel`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Staff}">
    <!-- ... -->
        <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, 
                                Path=IsSelected, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

При следующем коде VM реакция на изменение значения чекбокса (`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`) отсуствует:

```
private bool personSelected = false; // по умолчанию

public bool IsSelected {
    get { return personSelected; }
    set {
        personSelected = value;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(personSelected);
        OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }
}
```

Чего я недопонял в предыдущем вопросе?

Comment: А свойство `IsSelected` у вас где лежит? Просто `IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"` не работает?

Comment: @Андрей, в смысле, "где лежит"? Это свойство VM, где оно и объявлено. Объявление я привёл в последнем листинге.

Comment: Это свойство которой VM? Привязка точно срабатывает? [Скрин из VS Enterprise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsUTX.png)

Comment: Кстати, если привязка односторонняя, то смысла задавать `UpdateSourceTrigger` нету, например, здесь: `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PersonFullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: @Андрей, У меня работа с данными производится в дочернем окне, соответственно, это VM дочернего окна (а в VM главного пока особо ничего и нет).  Чекбокс нужен только для выбора строк для их последующего одновременного удаления.

Comment: Вы привязали к `ListView` коллекцию `Users`, которая содержит элементы типа `UserVm`, так? Свойство `IsSelected` определено в `UserVm`?

Comment: Похоже что нет... Коллекция `Users` содержит элементы типа `UserEntitiy` - сущностного класса. Данная коллекция формируется в VM дочернего окна. А `UserEntitiyViewModel` если нужна, то получается впервые понадобилась, я не знал о необходимости таковой... Дело в том, что коллекция `Users` будет использоваться в обоих окнах - главном и дочернем, поэтому нельзя сказать, что это модель, соответствующая именно дочернему окну.

Comment: Т.е. свойство `IsSelected` у вас лежит в главной VM?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67035/discussion-between-gurebu-bokofu-and-).